# Sending JSON data to a server with NODEJS HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, https, telegram-api

I am trying to make a `POST` request to [`api.telegram.org`](https://api.telegram.org) with `path` as [`/bot{token}/sendMessage`](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Btoken%7D/sendMessage). I have done it in the *client side* with `XMLHttpRequest`, but `nodejs` hav no support for `XMLHttpRequest`. So, the alternative is `https` module in `nodejs`. I had a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169906/nodejs-make-https-request-sending-json-data#42169981) and my code is:

---

```js
var https = require("https");
var bot_token = "1677044698:AAE3GG-Tpfwgra41lenP5sw0HCIX-ZoTlLA";

var params = {
  "chat_id": "1105434113",
  "text": "The bot is working..."
}

var postData = JSON.stringify(params);

var options = {
  hostname: "api.telegram.org",
  path: `/bot${bot_token}/sendMessage`,
  port: 80,   
  method: 'POST',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
}

var req = https.request(
options,
  (res)=>{
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
  }
)
req.on("error", (err)=>{
  console.log(err)
})


req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

---

But I am getting an error, that I have no idea about.

```sh
Error: write EPROTO 5912:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16) {
  errno: -4046,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

> ###### `Do not worry about the exposed bot-token, I have revoked it.`

And, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

looks like an ssl error. if the request is made through **https**, change it to **http**

Comment: but, when I used `http`, it said that `https` is unsupported. Because `api.telegram.org` has a SSL certificate.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713926/what-is-easy-way-to-create-and-use-a-self-signed-certification-for-a-telegram-we, also check this doc https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed